# Child object not rotating or turning (only moving) after parenting to a bone on MC Character Rig (Endertainer Rig Remastered v1.2)

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, parent

Okay, so I'm quite new to blender and I'm essentially just getting started with trying to learn everything about the program, and I've encountered my first problem that I have yet to find an answer for or fix...

While trying to learn how to make a Minecraft animation using the rig listed in the title, I wanted to provide my character with a sword for a practice animation. I know in order to make the sword move with the arm, I have to parent the sword to the armature bone (if I'm saying that right) by selecting the arm in pose mode, then going to object mode, selecting the sword and then shift clicking the arm, and using `ctrl+p - Bone` (unless it's click the sword then shift click the arm in object mode then go to pose mode and clicking on the hand/arm bone, I've tried both bones and both orders).

I can successfully get the sword to parent to the bone and move with the arm... but that's all it does, it'll move, but the sword won't turn or rotate with the hand
[image: Endertainer Rig at original position I set it to (I positioned the sword manually then parented it)]
[image: Endertainer Rig with arm bend, the sword still pointing the same way, not upward with the hand like I need it to]
Does anyone know how I can fix this? It seems to be an issue with just this rig because I tried the BPS Rig V.4 and it worked like a charm, but I'd prefer to use the Endertainer Rig.
[image: BPS Rig at original position I had set it to with sword manually placed then parented]
[image: BPS Rig with arm bend, sword pointing in the direction it should (what I'm trying to achieve with the Endertainer Rig)]

I hope I've been descriptive enough...

Answer (score 0):

You are parenting the sword to the IK bone and not to the FK.

Hand IK bone has no rotation so the sword can't copy it.
That could be the reason, but I can't help you without the .blend file.
[image: IK parenting]

[image: FK parenting]